# How to extract the telephone number from the webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to grab some telephone no. from a website, I don't know why I keep getting the wrong information.

I am using jupyter to run the code

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.europages.co.uk/KIDDYSTORES/00000003902113-191369001.html'
tel = []

# Setup webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 720)") 
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/h3')[0]
# //*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/h3
button.click()
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div/a'))!=0:      
    button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div/a')[0]
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[7]/ul/li/div[1]/a'))!=0:
    button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[7]/ul/li/div[1]/a')[0]
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div[1]/a'))!=0[0]:
    button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div[1]/a')[0]
button.click()


print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div/div').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/aside/div/div[1]/div[6]/ul/li/div/div').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Above are the code I am running, I expect to get '+33 141 57 22 81', but the actual output is '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'

```py
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('team-sh-tel').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

However, when I run the code individually in another cell in the jupyter it can prints out the desired phone no.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the *telephone no* from the website `https://www.europages.co.uk/KIDDYSTORES/00000003902113-191369001.html` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code block using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.europages.co.uk/KIDDYSTORES/00000003902113-191369001.html")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.click-tel.icon.icon-telephone"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.click-tel.icon.icon-telephone"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "info-tel-num"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Code block using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.europages.co.uk/KIDDYSTORES/00000003902113-191369001.html")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='click-tel icon icon-telephone']//a[text()='See phone number']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='click-tel icon icon-telephone']//a[text()='See phone number']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='click-tel icon icon-telephone']//a[text()='See phone number']//following::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  +33 141 57 22 81
  ```